# How to create a List with URIs and Time input in C#

Tags: c#, uwp

[I am trying to make a UWP app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSFKA.png)
 that sets Desktop wallpaper based on an input time. As you see in the picture, after choosing an Image you set a time and Add it to a list. on the specified time the Image will be applied as wallpaper through a background task. But I am missing an important step. I am trying to find a way to do those following two things.

- I want to create a list in a file in which the app can add the Image
  URI and time of display. and a way for the Background task to read
  it.
- UI can show the added images from the list with an option to remove one of them.

How can I implement what I mentioned in [the code I have](https://github.com/moutasem1989/ActiveDynamicWall) ?

```
//Pickup Image file
    private async void FilePickerWallpaper(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker pickerWallpaper = new FileOpenPicker();
        pickerWallpaper.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        pickerWallpaper.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        pickerWallpaper.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        pickerWallpaper.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        pickerWallpaper.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

        //Get to the App local folder
        StorageFolder appFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        // Create a subfoloder
        String timeNameFile = "TimeWallpaper";
        StorageFolder timeFolder = await appFolder.CreateFolderAsync(timeNameFile, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        //Check if the folder was created
        if (await appFolder.TryGetItemAsync(timeNameFile) != null) Debug.WriteLine("Folder" + timeNameFile + "exist");
        else Debug.WriteLine("Folder" + timeNameFile + "does not exist");

        //Pick an Image
        StorageFile fileName = await pickerWallpaper.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (fileName != null)
        {
            //Check if the file does not exist
            if (await timeFolder.TryGetItemAsync(fileName.Name) != null)
            {
                string selectedImgName = fileName.Name;
                await fileName.CopyAsync(timeFolder, selectedImgName, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                //Preview the Image on the interface
                selectImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///TimeWallpaper/" + selectedImgName));
            }
            else
            {
                selectImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/wallpaper.png"));
            }
        }
    }

    //add selected file to the List - w
    private void AddFile00(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BitmapImage bitImageSource = (BitmapImage)selectImg.Source;
    }

    //Oops! this is to remove the last added image to the list
    private void RemoveFile(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `if` condition (where you "check if the file does not exist") be using a `!= null` comparison?

Comment: Take a look at `File.AppendLine` and `File.ReadLines` for appending to and reading from a file. You also might consider creating a simple class that stores the image path and time stamp as properties, make it serializable, and then save/load the user's choices through serialization.

Comment: @Rufus Thank you .. I have missed that mistake ! 
I am looking at What you have mentioned.  The File.AppendLine seems to be a possible solution. Could you elaborate on the topic of creating a Class to store URIs and time stamps as properties? Is it possible to "bind" the collection to Xaml ?

Comment: I just meant create a simple class with two properties so you can keep them together: `public class BackgroundImage { public string ImageFilePath { get; set; } public DateTime ApplicationTime { get; set; } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're some errors in your code:

1. You're creating files in application install directory. The `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation` is read-only, you cannot write files in it. See [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) for more details. You could save the iamges files in [ApplicationData.LocalFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalFolder). I believe you've read the [UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.TrySetWallpaperImageAsync(StorageFile) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.userprofile.userprofilepersonalizationsettings.trysetwallpaperimageasync#Windows_System_UserProfile_UserProfilePersonalizationSettings_TrySetWallpaperImageAsync_Windows_Storage_StorageFile_), but you misunderstood the code on that document. On that document, it just gets the image file from application install directory, not write file in it. So, your code was not correct.
2. The code of your registering background task was not correct. The `TaskEntryPoint` in code and `Package.appxmanifest` should be "BackgroundTaskComponent.BackgroundClass". You'd better read the [Create and register an out-of-process background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task) document carefully, then you could start to use background task in your app.

Then, let's back to your original question:

> I want to create a list in a file in which the app can add the Image URI and time of display. and a way for the Background task to read it.

As @Rufus L said, you could define a class to keep them together. And then, you could save it in a file which is saved in `ApplicationData.LocalFolder`. When the background task is triggered, you could get it from `ApplicationData.LocalFolder`. There's a simple way to save the complex object. You could use [LocalObjectStorageHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/helpers/objectstorage) class of the Windows Community Toolkit.

The code looks like the following:

```
 var uri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/TimeWallpaper/" + assetsFileName);
 StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
 UserProfilePersonalizationSettings profileSettings = UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current;
 await profileSettings.TrySetWallpaperImageAsync(file);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback! it is so helpful
I did fix the issue with you brought to my attention regarding file access permission and the background task.
Through reading I found this potential solution  "ObservableCollection" in C# that can be used to store Image URIs and time stamps.
    `public ObservableCollection<Wallpaper> wallpapers = new ObservableCollection<Wallpaper>();`
If I had this as an input
 `(timePicker.Time.Hours, timePicker.Time.Minutes, selectedImage.Source)`

How can I save the collection to a file where I am able to retrieve a URI based on current time?

Comment: @AsemKhen As I said, you could use [LocalObjectStorageHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/helpers/objectstorage) to save complex/large object. There's code sample on that document.

Comment: The personalization feature in UWP seems to be finally working in my app. However, it feels like the fade effect when changing from one wallpaper to another is not working!. How do I fix this? I only could find answers for legacy desktop applications

Comment: @AsemKhen There's no such API for you to apply fade effect when you use the `TrySetWallpaperImageAsync` method to change the wallpaper.